# How to fix code to sent (name,email,phone,body massage) from android to mail

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I use this code to send details to email from android but I just receive body mail only and did not recive name,phone and email .
this my code :

```js
public class ActivityContactUs extends Activity {
    EditText name ,email,phone,body;
    Button send;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contact_us);
        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone);
        body = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.body);
        send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
   }
    public void SendBtn(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("plain/text");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                new String[]{getResources().getString(R.string.email_address)});
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
        String name_email = name.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, name_email);
        String email_email = email.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, email_email);
        String phone_email = phone.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, phone_email);
        String body_email = body.getText().toString() + "\n\n Sent from Ecommerce Android App";
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body_email);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send email..."), 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: When you call `intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, phone_email);` you are overwriting the key / value pair you just set with `intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, phone_email);` - If you wish to pass this text along as the body of the message, then you should assemble one large body string, and pass that to the intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

type order of intent is wrong

```
intent.setType("plain/text");
```

should be `intent.setType("text/plain");`

another problem: `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT` should be used for only one extra to avoid setting different values associated with the same key

Comment: try it again by using new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)

Comment: The problem is still  I do not receive in the email only the body of the message
I do not receive the name     Mobile
Your Email

Comment: you're using same key for different extras so please try to change key Intent.EXTRA_TEXT

Comment: Can u edit my code in your answer please. Sorry for my bad language